# Call method immediately after C# object has been initialised by Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

### Summary

I have a class that should **track whether a property's value has been changed** by the user and **remember its original value** to allow resetting or committing it. Therefore, I wrote a class `Historian<T>` that serves as a wrapper and will be used in the business models of my application. However, **when Entity Framework Core (EFC) gets my data from the database (DB), my approach results in indicating the value as edited and having stored an incorrect original value**, i.e. `default(T)`.

### Details on the Question

This is the wrapper to remember the original and current value of a property:

```
public class Historian<T>
{
    public T OriginalValue { get; private set; }
    public T CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsEdited => object.Equals(OriginalValue, CurrentValue); // avoids NullPointerExceptions

    // some events ValueChanged, EditsDiscarded, EditsCommitted

    public void CommitChanges()
        => OriginalValue = CurrentValue;

    public void DiscardChanges()
        => CurrentValue = OriginalValue;
}
```

For illustrative purposes, let's stick with the classic library example. This is my `Book` class. The property `Title` should remember its original value from the DB accessed via EFC and allow resetting it internally or from other classes. The idea is that users will be shown the original value when editing text boxes in an application and allow resetting individual fields.

```
public class Book
{
    private Historian<string> _Title = new Historian<string>();

    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Title
    {
        get => _Title.CurrentValue;
        set => _Title.CurrentValue = value;
    }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsPopularBook { get; set; }

    // other methods, properties, ..., this is an example
}
```

Now the problem is that when EFC gets the data from the database, it uses the default constructor, initialising `Book.Title` to `string.Empty` (setting both `Historian.OriginalValue` and `Historian.CurrentValue`) and then, after the constructor finished, sets `Book.Title`, to a value, let's say "Markdown -- a Pocket Guide". This, however, makes it seem to the application that the value was changed, even though it was not.

Is there a way to distinguish whether an object was constructed by EFC or by other parts of the application? Can I intercept the constructor called by EFC to initialise my `Historian.OriginalValue` correctly? Or can I tell EFC to call a method after the object has been initialised to set the `Historian.OriginalValue`, e.g. by calling `Historian.CommitChanges()` (though semantically wrong, I think you get the idea).

### Non-Solutions -- (Failed) Attempts

Adding a constructor with parameters for the properties did work as EFC then calls this constructor, i.e.

```
public Book(string title)
{
    Title = title;
    _Title.CommitChanges();
}
```

However, as soon as there is a **parameterless constructor** (which I need in places in the application), **EFC ignores the one with the parameters**.

I tried **changing the getter and setter of the property**, which also did work. However, now I **cannot easily subscribe to the events of `Historian`** which was `null` before.

```
private Historian<string> _Title ;

public string Title
{
    get
    {
        if (_Title == null)
            _Title = new Historian<string>();
        return _Title.CurrentValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_Title == null)
        {
            _Title = new Historian<string>();
            _Title.CurrentValue = value;
            _Title.CommitChanges();
        }
        else
            _Title.CurrentValue = value;
    }
}
```

Then, my idea was to have a fixed instance of `Historian` where I can subscribe to the events and *add an initialisation mode to it*, e.g. via a `bool FirstSetterInitialises`. But here, I **cannot distinguish whether I'm initialising from EFC or somewhere else**, so also new instances of `Book` will indicate they are not edited for the first edit, even though they are.

Comment: I think you should use the [ChangeTracker.Tracked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.tracked?view=efcore-6.0) event.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Entity Framework change tracking.  Consider the Historian class below that has been refactored to use Entity Framework change tracking.  One caveat to this approach is that the Historians have to be instantiated with a reference to the EF context that created them, so this is an extra step that you would have to call from the layer above Entity Framework.  One benefit of this approach is that it doesn't require any additional overhead to perform the change tracking - EF is already going to be doing the work anyways (unless you query with .AsNoTracking).

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Historian<Role, string> NameHistorian;

    /// <summary>
    /// call this function after an EF context has returned this entity to build the historian
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">the Entity Framework context that returned this entity</param>
    public void ConfigureHistorians(DbContext context)
    {
        NameHistorian = new Historian<Role, string>(context, this, entity => entity.Name);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// a utility to view whether an property on a tracked entity has changed as well as the previous value
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="EntityType">the entity model class</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="DataType">the type of the property to be tracked</typeparam>
public class Historian<EntityType, DataType> where EntityType : class where DataType : IEquatable<DataType>
{
    private Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.PropertyEntry<EntityType, DataType> efEntry;

    /// <summary>
    /// create a historian for a specific property on a given entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">the Entity Framework context from which the entity was retrieved</param>
    /// <param name="entity">the instance of the entity this historian is tracking</param>
    /// <param name="propertySelector">the property of the entity this historian is tracking</param>
    public Historian(DbContext context, EntityType entity,
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<EntityType, DataType>> propertySelector)
    {
        efEntry = context.Entry<EntityType>(entity).Property<DataType>(propertySelector);
    }

    public DataType OriginalValue => efEntry.OriginalValue;
    public DataType CurrentValue => efEntry.CurrentValue;
    public bool IsEdited => !CurrentValue.Equals(OriginalValue);
    public void DiscardChanges()
        => efEntry.CurrentValue = efEntry.OriginalValue;
}
```